# Highlight / Add Class to active div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have a website and I want it so that, as you scroll the div or section of the website at the top of the screen, or first on screen, has a class added to it, with a box shadow etc. As you can see by running my code snippet below, I have successfully made it scroll to div on click, and add a class, however, I would like to have it add a class when user scrolls to div. I would like to use jQuery and no external plugins.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("nav ul li a").on('click', function() {
    var Target = $(this).attr("anchor");
    var Location = $("#" + Target).position();

    $(".content").removeClass("active");
    $("#" + Target).addClass("active");

    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: Location.top - 30
    }, 350);
  });
  $(".content").on("click", function() {
    $(".content").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    var Location = $(this).position();
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: Location.top - 30
    }, 350);
  });
  $(window).click(function() {
    $(".content").removeClass("active");
  });

  $('.content,nav ul li a').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 3em;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.content {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  width: 80%;
}

.content p {
  max-width: 900px;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .header {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.25em 5%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 5%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border: solid transparent 1px;
  }
  .header:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  nav ul li a:hover {
    color: black;
    background: white;
  }
  .content {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media (max-width:700px) {
  .header {
    display: none;
  }
  .content {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    width: 80%;
  }
}

.active {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a anchor="home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a anchor="services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a anchor="safety">Safety</a></li>
          <li><a anchor="about">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a anchor="contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="home" class="content">
      <h1>My Random Website</h1>
      <p>Latin was originally spoken in the area around Rome, known as Latium.[4] Through the power of the Roman Republic, it became the dominant language, initially in Italy and subsequently throughout the western Roman Empire. Vulgar Latin developed into
        the Romance languages, such as Italian, Portuguese, Spanish, French, and Romanian. Latin, Greek, and French have contributed many words to the English language. In particular, Latin (and Ancient Greek) roots are used in English descriptions of
        theology, biology, science, medicine, and law.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="services" class="content">
      <h1>Services</h1>
      <p>Latin was originally spoken in the area around Rome, known as Latium.[4] Through the power of the Roman Republic, it became the dominant language, initially in Italy and subsequently throughout the western Roman Empire. Vulgar Latin developed into
        the Romance languages, such as Italian, Portuguese, Spanish, French, and Romanian. Latin, Greek, and French have contributed many words to the English language. In particular, Latin (and Ancient Greek) roots are used in English descriptions of
        theology, biology, science, medicine, and law.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="safety" class="content">
      <h1>Safety</h1>
      <p>Latin was originally spoken in the area around Rome, known as Latium.[4] Through the power of the Roman Republic, it became the dominant language, initially in Italy and subsequently throughout the western Roman Empire. Vulgar Latin developed into
        the Romance languages, such as Italian, Portuguese, Spanish, French, and Romanian. Latin, Greek, and French have contributed many words to the English language. In particular, Latin (and Ancient Greek) roots are used in English descriptions of
        theology, biology, science, medicine, and law.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="about" class="content">
      <h1>About</h1>
      <p>Latin was originally spoken in the area around Rome, known as Latium.[4] Through the power of the Roman Republic, it became the dominant language, initially in Italy and subsequently throughout the western Roman Empire. Vulgar Latin developed into
        the Romance languages, such as Italian, Portuguese, Spanish, French, and Romanian. Latin, Greek, and French have contributed many words to the English language. In particular, Latin (and Ancient Greek) roots are used in English descriptions of
        theology, biology, science, medicine, and law.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contact" class="content">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
      Latin was originally spoken in the area around Rome, known as Latium.[4] Through the power of the Roman Republic, it became the dominant language, initially in Italy and subsequently throughout the western Roman Empire. Vulgar Latin developed into the
      Romance languages, such as Italian, Portuguese, Spanish, French, and Romanian. Latin, Greek, and French have contributed many words to the English language. In particular, Latin (and Ancient Greek) roots are used in English descriptions of theology,
      biology, science, medicine, and law.
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using below **jQuery** ,you can active class on scroll when reach at top

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){  
     var topMenuHeight = $('.header').outerHeight() + 30;
     var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop() + topMenuHeight; 
     $('.content').each(function() {
       if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop){
         var id = $(this).attr('id');
         $('.content').removeClass('active');
         $('#'+ id).addClass('active');
       }
       else{
         var id = $(this).attr('id');
         $('#'+ id).removeClass('active');
       }  
     });
   });
  $("nav ul li a").on('click', function() {
    var Target = $(this).attr("anchor");
    var Location = $("#" + Target).position();

    $(".content").removeClass("active");
    $("#" + Target).addClass("active");

    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: Location.top - 30
    }, 350);
  });
  $(".content").on("click", function() {
    $(".content").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    var Location = $(this).position();
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: Location.top - 30
    }, 350);
  });
  $(window).click(function() {
    $(".content").removeClass("active");
  });

  $('.content,nav ul li a').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 3em;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.content {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  width: 80%;
}

.content p {
  max-width: 900px;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .header {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.25em 5%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 5%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border: solid transparent 1px;
  }
  .header:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  nav ul li a:hover {
    color: black;
    background: white;
  }
  .content {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media (max-width:700px) {
  .header {
    display: none;
  }
  .content {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    width: 80%;
  }
}

.active {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a anchor="home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a anchor="services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a anchor="safety">Safety</a></li>
          <li><a anchor="about">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a anchor="contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="home" class="content">
      <h1>My Random Website</h1>
      <p>Latin was originally spoken in the area around Rome, known as Latium.[4] Through the power of the Roman Republic, it became the dominant language, initially in Italy and subsequently throughout the western Roman Empire. Vulgar Latin developed into
        the Romance languages, such as Italian, Portuguese, Spanish, French, and Romanian. Latin, Greek, and French have contributed many words to the English language. In particular, Latin (and Ancient Greek) roots are used in English descriptions of
        theology, biology, science, medicine, and law.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="services" class="content">
      <h1>Services</h1>
      <p>Latin was originally spoken in the area around Rome, known as Latium.[4] Through the power of the Roman Republic, it became the dominant language, initially in Italy and subsequently throughout the western Roman Empire. Vulgar Latin developed into
        the Romance languages, such as Italian, Portuguese, Spanish, French, and Romanian. Latin, Greek, and French have contributed many words to the English language. In particular, Latin (and Ancient Greek) roots are used in English descriptions of
        theology, biology, science, medicine, and law.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="safety" class="content">
      <h1>Safety</h1>
      <p>Latin was originally spoken in the area around Rome, known as Latium.[4] Through the power of the Roman Republic, it became the dominant language, initially in Italy and subsequently throughout the western Roman Empire. Vulgar Latin developed into
        the Romance languages, such as Italian, Portuguese, Spanish, French, and Romanian. Latin, Greek, and French have contributed many words to the English language. In particular, Latin (and Ancient Greek) roots are used in English descriptions of
        theology, biology, science, medicine, and law.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="about" class="content">
      <h1>About</h1>
      <p>Latin was originally spoken in the area around Rome, known as Latium.[4] Through the power of the Roman Republic, it became the dominant language, initially in Italy and subsequently throughout the western Roman Empire. Vulgar Latin developed into
        the Romance languages, such as Italian, Portuguese, Spanish, French, and Romanian. Latin, Greek, and French have contributed many words to the English language. In particular, Latin (and Ancient Greek) roots are used in English descriptions of
        theology, biology, science, medicine, and law.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contact" class="content">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
      Latin was originally spoken in the area around Rome, known as Latium.[4] Through the power of the Roman Republic, it became the dominant language, initially in Italy and subsequently throughout the western Roman Empire. Vulgar Latin developed into the
      Romance languages, such as Italian, Portuguese, Spanish, French, and Romanian. Latin, Greek, and French have contributed many words to the English language. In particular, Latin (and Ancient Greek) roots are used in English descriptions of theology,
      biology, science, medicine, and law.
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, however, is there any way for me to make it only one div active at any time.

Comment: @Jacob Check updated snippet for only one active class

Comment: Oh, that was a simple fix I should have seen that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("nav ul li a").on('click', function() {
    var Target = $(this).attr("anchor");
    var Location = $("#" + Target).position();

    $(".content").removeClass("active");
    $("#" + Target).addClass("active");

    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: Location.top - 30
    }, 350);
  });
  $(".content").on("click", function() {
    $(".content").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    var Location = $(this).position();
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: Location.top - 30
    }, 350);
  });
  $(window).click(function() {
    $(".content").removeClass("active");
  });
  var start = $('.content').first();
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  $(document).scroll(function(event){
     var st = $(this).scrollTop();
     if (st > lastScrollTop){
        if($(this).scrollTop()>= start.position().top){
                updateClass();
          start = start.next();        
        }
     } else {
        if($(this).scrollTop()<= start.position().top){
                updateClass();
          start = start.prev();        
        }
     }
     lastScrollTop = st;
  }); 
    function updateClass(){
      $(".content").removeClass("active");
        start.addClass("active");
  } 

  $('.content,nav ul li a').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 3em;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.content {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  width: 80%;
}

.content p {
  max-width: 900px;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .header {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.25em 5%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 5%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border: solid transparent 1px;
  }
  .header:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  nav ul li a:hover {
    color: black;
    background: white;
  }
  .content {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    width: 80%;
  }
}

@media (max-width:700px) {
  .header {
    display: none;
  }
  .content {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    width: 80%;
  }
}

.active {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a anchor="home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a anchor="services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a anchor="safety">Safety</a></li>
          <li><a anchor="about">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a anchor="contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="home" class="content">
      <h1>My Random Website</h1>
      <p>Latin was originally spoken in the area around Rome, known as Latium.[4] Through the power of the Roman Republic, it became the dominant language, initially in Italy and subsequently throughout the western Roman Empire. Vulgar Latin developed into
        the Romance languages, such as Italian, Portuguese, Spanish, French, and Romanian. Latin, Greek, and French have contributed many words to the English language. In particular, Latin (and Ancient Greek) roots are used in English descriptions of
        theology, biology, science, medicine, and law.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="services" class="content">
      <h1>Services</h1>
      <p>Latin was originally spoken in the area around Rome, known as Latium.[4] Through the power of the Roman Republic, it became the dominant language, initially in Italy and subsequently throughout the western Roman Empire. Vulgar Latin developed into
        the Romance languages, such as Italian, Portuguese, Spanish, French, and Romanian. Latin, Greek, and French have contributed many words to the English language. In particular, Latin (and Ancient Greek) roots are used in English descriptions of
        theology, biology, science, medicine, and law.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="safety" class="content">
      <h1>Safety</h1>
      <p>Latin was originally spoken in the area around Rome, known as Latium.[4] Through the power of the Roman Republic, it became the dominant language, initially in Italy and subsequently throughout the western Roman Empire. Vulgar Latin developed into
        the Romance languages, such as Italian, Portuguese, Spanish, French, and Romanian. Latin, Greek, and French have contributed many words to the English language. In particular, Latin (and Ancient Greek) roots are used in English descriptions of
        theology, biology, science, medicine, and law.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="about" class="content">
      <h1>About</h1>
      <p>Latin was originally spoken in the area around Rome, known as Latium.[4] Through the power of the Roman Republic, it became the dominant language, initially in Italy and subsequently throughout the western Roman Empire. Vulgar Latin developed into
        the Romance languages, such as Italian, Portuguese, Spanish, French, and Romanian. Latin, Greek, and French have contributed many words to the English language. In particular, Latin (and Ancient Greek) roots are used in English descriptions of
        theology, biology, science, medicine, and law.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contact" class="content">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
      Latin was originally spoken in the area around Rome, known as Latium.[4] Through the power of the Roman Republic, it became the dominant language, initially in Italy and subsequently throughout the western Roman Empire. Vulgar Latin developed into the
      Romance languages, such as Italian, Portuguese, Spanish, French, and Romanian. Latin, Greek, and French have contributed many words to the English language. In particular, Latin (and Ancient Greek) roots are used in English descriptions of theology,
      biology, science, medicine, and law.
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Below is my code

```
var start = $('.content').first();
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  $(document).scroll(function(event){
     var st = $(this).scrollTop();
     if (st > lastScrollTop){
        if($(this).scrollTop()>= start.position().top){
                updateClass();
          start = start.next();        
        }
     } else {
        if($(this).scrollTop()<= start.position().top){
                updateClass();
          start = start.prev();        
        }
     }
     lastScrollTop = st;
  }); 
    function updateClass(){
      $(".content").removeClass("active");
        start.addClass("active");
  }
```